# Adding a proper title to ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've been trying this all morning and still can't find a solution after reading related post on stackoverflow

I have the following code:

```
names <- colnames(df[17:length(df)])

counter = 17L

for (i in 1:length(names)) {
  df.tax <- subset(df, df[,c(counter)] != 0)
  counter = counter + 1L
  meta <- subset(df.tax, select=c(1:16))
  meltmeta <- melt(meta, id=c("Collector", "Year","Week","Cities","Provinces"))
  ppv <- ggplot(meltmeta, aes(title = paste(names[i]), factor(Provinces), value))
  ppv + geom_boxplot() + geom_boxplot(aes(fill=Collector), alpha=I(0.5)) + geom_point(aes(color=Collector), size=1) +facet_wrap(~variable, scale="free")
  ggsave(file = paste(names[i], sep=".","provinces_vs_climate.pdf"), width=16, height=8)
}
```

My issue is, I can't add a proper title for ggplot. At every iteration of the for loop, I am generating a new dataframe called df.tax by subsetting parts of df. I melt df and then trying to generate a plot using ggplot.

I managed to save each plot with a different file name (based on the names array) every iteration on ggsave, but ggplot just keep on generating the title "paste(names[i])" for each plot.

I tried, get(), paste(), labs()...etc, but none work

Anyone know how I can resolve this issue?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As mentioned by [joran](https://stackoverflow.com/users/324364/joran), since version 0.9.2 of ggplot2, the easiest way to set a title for your plot is to use [`ggtitle`](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/labs.html). Using `ggtitle` your code would look something like this:

```
for (i in 1:length(names)) {
  df.tax <- subset(df, df[,c(counter)] != 0)
  counter = counter + 1L
  meta <- subset(df.tax, select=c(1:16))
  meltmeta <- melt(meta, id=c("Collector", "Year","Week","Cities","Provinces"))
  ppv <- ggplot(meltmeta, aes(factor(Provinces), value))
  ppv <- ppv + geom_boxplot() 
  ppv <- ppv + geom_boxplot(aes(fill=Collector), alpha=I(0.5)) 
  ppv <- ppv + geom_point(aes(color=Collector), size=1) 
  ppv <- ppv + facet_wrap(~variable, scale="free")
  ppv <- ppv + ggtitle(paste(names[i]))
  ggsave(file = paste(names[i], sep=".","provinces_vs_climate.pdf"), width=16, height=8)
}
```

Comment: No need to link to my profile, or even mention me really. If I restrict myself to a comment it's because I don't have time/inclination to write an answer, and fully expect others to do so. :)

Comment: I'll remove the link if you'd prefer. Although I'm glad I clicked through it, personally, as I'm a fellow nordic skier/data analyst (what a pleasant surprise).

Comment: No need to remove it...just letting you know it's totally fine to poach any of my comments as answers, that's all.

Comment: Thank you very much! I didn't know about ggtitle